# select2 jquery all option should become readonly. ie., all drop down values should be visible but not clickable

Tags: jquery

I am using json value for two dropdown list using select2 in jquery.Here i need to make my second dropdown as readonly.All options should be visible.But not clickable.I tryed with disable but the total dropdown gets disable. Dropdown is not happening.

[view this link. In this link i found one example which should become only view .ie., readable not selectable.](http://www.bootstrap4xpages.com/bs4xp/demos.nsf/Bootstrap_Select2Listbox.xsp)

Comment: You can change the selected index back to the required value in the onchange event (be wary of creating and endless loop) OR you can return false on the mousedown event of the options inside the select (ddl). Just remember to test it when a user selects a value with the keyboard

Comment: instead of this is there any built in methods or something like that which will be more useful for me. for eg., to disable we setting disable to true. I need somthing like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways:

(1) Add a handler for the `'select2-selecting'` event that calls `.preventDefault()` on the event object. That will stop an item from being selected.

```
$('#select').select2({
    ...
}).on('select2-selecting', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

If you want the drop-down to still close when an item is clicked, you can do this:

```
$('#select').select2({
    ...
}).on('select2-selecting', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).select2('close');
});
```

And if you don't want the search box, you can set the `minimumResultsForSearch` option to a negative number.

```
$('#select').select2({
    ...
    minimumResultsForSearch: -1
})
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5jrcq01p/2/)

---

(2) As [@JayRizzi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27575246/859640) to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27575246/859640) shows, you could mark all the choices as disabled, rather than the entire Select2 control.

```
$('#select').select2({
    data: [
        id: 'id1', text: 'choice 1', disabled: true,
        ...
    ],
    ...
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5jrcq01p/3/)