# Disable select2 plugin in JQuery dropdown

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-select2

I am getting the values from json and displaying it in a popup. I need to disable that option which i am getting from json. How can i do that?

I tried normal jQuery but It doesn't work. I tried disabled true that also not working.

Please give solution.

Comment: Please show your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the select2 docs

> In case that you need to disable certain options so that they can't be selected by the select2 interface, you can now pass in disabled: true with your data. Please note: This also works for incoming values from ajax. When attached to a  element, Select2 will respect its  elements' disabled property.

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    $( '#e24' ).select2( {
        query: function( query ) {
            var data = {
                results: [
                    { id: 1, text: "I'm selectable" },
                    { id: 2, text: "I'm a disabled option", disabled: true },
                    { id: 3, text: "I'm selectable too!" }
                ]
            };

            query.callback( data );
        }
    } );
} );
```